# How to update Entity Framework with deserialized object?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, deserialization

I have one method that looks like this:

```
// Adds an element to the TableElement table in SQL
AddToSql(TableElement deserializedObject)
{
    MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
    entities.TableElement.AddObject(deserializedObject);
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've tried to write a similar method to update existing rows, but my method doesn't work

```
// Doesn't work
UpdateSql(TableElement deserializedObject)
{
    MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
    int id = deserializedObject.id;
    TableElement elementToOverwrite = entities.TableElement
        .Single(s => s.Id == deserializedObject.Id);
    // Somehow, I want to give "elementToOverwrite" all the values in "deserializedObject"

    // I NEED TO KNOW WHAT GOES HERE.

    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Update: It looks like I can use `entities.ApplyCurrentValues("TableElement", deserializedObject)`, **but** if my deserialized object contains related rows in other tables, those will not be affected.

Comment: There is no shortcut to applying changes to an object graph. You'll have to ApplyCurrentValues to all child objects too.

Comment: Oh, but it's more complicated than that!  There may be some child obects that are entirely new, while others may be modified or deleted.